# spring mvc+ajax geting data on click

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a form controller.Form element is a drop down box.

For eg there is user name form element.if user select his name .I want the children names to be loaded for particular user.

I have List getChildernByUser(User user);

Please would like to know how this can be made using jquery or ajax.If user is selected in next form element he gets all his children to select .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the server side, I'd use a controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/users/{userId}/children")
public @ResponseBody List<User> getChilden(@PathVariable String userId) { ... }
```

More info in this kind of controller methods can be found in the [Spring reference doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody). You'll also need the [Jackson libraries](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) in your `/lib` folder for Spring MVC to convert the bean to JSON.

Then, in your client code (HTML) you can use the [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function to make an Ajax call and get a List of users in JSON format.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you.If i dont want to use json.I would like to use ajax+jquery?

Comment: I think you're not very experienced with Ajax. jQuery is a Javascript library that allows to make Ajax calls (apart from a lot of useful functions), but these Ajax calls have to give some kind of response for your browser notice the success/error of the remote operation. The format of this response usually is XML or JSON. I choose JSON because is lighter than XML, but you could make it with XML.